# About constructor and assignment operator in C++

Tags: c++

### I am learning cpp, and now have a problem. Here are the code and the result.

What I very want to know are why there is only one constructor between "1" and "2" and why there are assignment and constructor between "3" and "4".

### Thank you in advance

[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hmxe.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    A(){
        cout << "Empty-constructor" << endl;
    }
    A(const A &a){
        cout << "Copy-constructor" << endl;
        this->v = a.v;
    }
    A operator=(const A &a){
        cout << "Assignment" << endl;
        this->v = a.v;
        return *this;
    }
    int get(){
        return v;
    }
    void set(int v){
        this->v = v;
    }
private:
    int v;
};

A func(){
    A a;
    return a;
}

int main(){
    cout << "1" << endl;
    A b = func();
    cout << "2" << endl;
    A c;
    cout << "3" << endl;
    c = b;
    cout << "4" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A b = func();` only produces construction due to [copy elision/NRVO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12953127/364696); the new `A` is constructed directly into the caller's memory.

`b = c;` involves both assignment and construction because you wrote your assignment operator incorrectly, having it return by value, rather than by reference, so after the assignment is performed, it copy-constructs from the object you've just assigned to, returning the copy (which isn't used, and gets thrown away immediately). That's a giant waste, and should really be fixed to make the assignment operator return by reference, changing:

```
A operator=(const A &a){
```

to:

```
A& operator=(const A &a){
```

Even better, use [the copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/364696) to avoid duplicating code for copying/swapping all over the place.

Comment: @user4581301: Thanks. I decided on linking the copy-and-swap idiom question rather than the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading, since the assignment operator specifically gets rather short shrift in the basic rules and idioms question.

Comment: Agreed. A better targeted choice.